# Customer Attributes & Customer Address Attributes Export/Import

Tags: magento-enterprise, admin, attributes, customer

I am trying to export and import via MySQL the customer attributes & customer address attributes. There are 9 instances of Magento that I manage and I've set up the validation rules on 1 instance. I would like to copy this across.

I do not want to copy across customer data, just the attributes and its data like validation.
What tables should I export and import to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`customer_eav_attribute` seem to contain all customer related attribute data and its meta data.